# With CSS have fixed headers inside scroll elements and be responsive to elements when made smaller

Tags: html, css

Is it possible with CSS to have two fixed headers which when made responsive affect the content of the scrollable element. I.e. has the headers gets bigger it pushes down the content below.

I am trying to do it with flex boxes, but stuck on having a second fixed header within and scroll element.

http://codepen.io/labithiotis/pen/tkAlB

Want to avoid using lots of media query or js. feel like there must be a solution with flex box.

Comment: Elements that are positioned absolute or fixed are taken out of the layout flow – and that fact can not be changed by flexbox.

Comment: Yes aware of that, but thought i could make two divs using flex box and the second only scroll inside. but failed at doing so.

Comment: So to clarify, in your CodePend example, you want the pink box to stay in a fixed position and adjust to the size of the yellow menu items?

Comment: yer, but also the black boxs to adjust to new size :)